# How do I change a remote application's logback log level through http (rest)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logback

How do I change a remote application's logback log level through http (rest)? to

```
@Controller
public class ChangeLog2Controller {

    @PostMapping("/api/testlog1")
    public ResponseModel testLogeBack(@RequestBody LogLevelModel levelModel) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ...

```
@PostMapping("/api/testlog1")
public ResponseModel testLogeBack(@RequestBody LogLevelModel levelModel) {
    // change the log level for the root logger
    Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    rootLogger.setLevel(...);

    // change the log level for a specific logger
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    Logger specificLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("com.some.specific.package");
    specificLogger.setLevel(...);
}
```

... where the parameter passed into `setLevel()` is something like `Level.INFO` which would, I presume, be derived from your `LogLevelModel`.

Note: if you are looking for some way to dynamically change logging configuration and a JMX client (rather than a HTTP client) would suffice then Logback already provides a [JMX Configurator](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/jmxConfig.html) which yuou can engage by simply adding the following to your logback.xml: `<jmxConfigurator />`. This exposes a JMX MBean which you can use to view and set log levels.

**Edit 1**: based on the comments below it seems like your requirement might be to invoke `WebApplicationA` and somehow enable `WebApplicationA` to change the log level for loggers **inside** `WebApplicationB`? If so, then either

- `WebApplicationA` has to use the JMXConfigurator MBean exposed by `WebApplicationB`. There are examples of Java JMX clients [here](http://www.journaldev.com/1359/java-jmx-client-example-authentication) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/custom.html). However, in order to expose the JMXConfigurator you must have some control over `WebApplicationB`'s logback.xml and, if so, then perhaps you also have some control over `WebApplicationB`'s implementation in which case it might be easier to just expose a simple `setLogLevel` REST endpoint in `WebApplicationB` and let `WebApplicationA` invoke that rather than playing around with a Java JMX client.

  Or
- `WebApplicationB` has to expose a `changeLogLevel` REST API (with an implementation like the one I provided above) which `WebApplicationA` can invoke.

The only other alternative is that `WebApplicationA` somehow changes the logback.xml used by `WebApplicationB` and `WebApplicationB`'s logback.xml starts looks like this ...

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds" >
    ...
</configuration>
```

... so that any changes made to this file on `WebApplicationB`'s classpath are picked up within (for example) 30 seconds. But, since `WebApplicationB`'s logback.xml is likely to be embedded in a WAR (or similar) this approach seems very awkward and very likely undesireable.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
But I just want to call the remote web-application‘s ’http-rest- api  through jmx (logback) modify the logback log level.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not able to understand your last message. Perhaps you are asking whether you can invoke Logback's `JMXConfigurator` via your REST API? I'm afraid the comment just isn't clear to me. So ... if you want to modify a log level via your REST API call then see my example above., if you want to do so via JMX then use Logback's `JMXConfigurator`.

Comment: thank you!I want to modify a log level via myREST API call,

Comment: Ok in that case the example I supplied above (where you get the `rootLogger` or the `specificLogger` and then `setLevel()`) is valid.

Comment: but my log system use logback.xml,and I want to change others web application‘s log level in one application via REST API.

Comment: It seems like your requirement might be to invoke WebApplicationA and somehow enable WebApplicationA to change the log level for loggers inside WebApplicationB? If so, I have updated the answer to address this.

Comment: right,I want to invoke WebApplicationA then  to change the log level for WebApplicationB,but the two applications are independent，can I change the log level of WebApplicationB by calling WebApplicationB-exposed MBean or WebApplicationB 's logback...I dont want to call WebApplicationB's REST API

Comment: I have updated the answer to include links to examples of custom JMX clients and to reiterate that exposing a `setLogLevel` endpoint in `WebApplicationB` is likely the simplest solution. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you.This problem I have handled it，by learning your  examples of Java JMX clients .